# How add multiple locale EULA in wixtoolset using addinExpress Editor

Tags: addin-express

I am trying to add multiple locale EULA in setup file. I am using Addinexpress editor. My code is following

```
 <Text SourceFile="!(loc.StdUI_ENU_LicenseRtf)" />   in  StandardUI.wxs and 

 <String Id="StdUI_ENU_LicenseRtf" Overridable="yes">EULA_en-us.rtf</String> in StandardUI_en-US.wxl
```

for english culture.
But I am getting error

The localization variable !(loc.StdUI_ENU_LicenseRtf) is unknown.  Please ensure the variable is defined.

Comment: Have you tried to post such questions on their forums instead?

Comment: yes, I post there also with same title.